# How to find the GCDs of LCMs of all pairs of elements in the given sequence.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, programming

You are given a sequence $A$ of positive numbers where the number will not be larger than $200,000$.
A multiset is created from the given sequence such that: $S = \{LCM(a_{i}, a_{j}) \;|\; i < j\}$. Design an algorithm that computes the $GCD(S)$.

**Constraints**
$1 \leq length(A) \leq 10^{5}$
$1 \leq a_{i} \leq 2 \times 10^{5}$ where $a_{i}$ represents the elements of the sequence $A$.

**For Example:**

1. $A = \{10, 24, 40, 80\}$ then the multi-set $S$ for the given sequence will be $S = \{120, 40, 80, 120, 240, 80\}$ and $GCD(S) = 40$.
2. $A = \{540, 648, 810, 648, 720\}$ then the multi-set $S$ for the given sequence will be $S = \{3240, 1620, 3240, 2160, 3240, 648, 6480, 3240, 6480, 6480\}$ and $GCD(S) = 108$.

I can't think of an algorithm that has a time-complexity better than $O(n^{2}\;log(a_{i},b_{i}))$ where $a_{i}, b_{i}$ are pairs of numbers considered and $log()$ is due to fact that for the calculation of $LCM(a, b)$ we need to compute $GCD(a, b)$ and time complexity of computing $GCD(a, b)$ using Eucledian Algorithm is $O(log(a \times b))$.

Comment: What does "multi-set" mean? It's just a usual set, right? Also this look like a programming challenge, so it would be better if you give the source of the problem, so that people know that it is not from an ongoing contest.

Comment: @WhatsUp Ya I also thought so but in the problem statement, they said it is a multi-set. This problem is not from any ongoing contest rather I posted it here because I am not able to understand the editorial for the given problem.

Comment: @WhatsUp Problem Statement: https://codeforces.com/contest/1349/problem/A

Comment: This is a *programming* question, not a *mathematics* question, and hence should be migrated.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes sir, you are right but as the problem-solution, is built upon the concepts of number theory, that's why I posted it here.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: No, it is not a programming question. The two answers posted so far contain no programming knowledge at all. It is an _algorithmic_ question (and there is a tag for these).

Answer (score 3):

For a prime number $p$ and an integer $n$, we write $v_p(n)$ for the $p$-adic valuation of $n$, i.e. the exponent of $p$ in the factorisation of $n$.

It is easy to see that $v_p(\gcd(S))$ is the second smallest element of $\{v_p(a): a \in A\}$.

Hence an algorithm goes as follows:

1. Factorize the first two elements in $A$. Let $P$ be the set of prime numbers appearing in at least one of these two factorizations. It is clear that $P$ is a quite small set ($< 15$). Also, any prime factor of $\gcd(S)$ must be in $P$.
2. Go through the sequence $A$, keeping a record of the smallest and second smallest exponents for every $p\in P$.

Comment: A distinct improvement on my algorithm! I didn't notice that you can ignore all primes that don't occur in the first two elements. (And this set of primes will get even smaller as you go through $A$.)

Comment: Thanks! I understood the algorithm. Can you tell me in brief why the algorithm works, the correctness of algorithm proof?

Answer (score 1):

Given a prime $p$, its power in the gcd's of lcm pairs is simply the second-lowest power of $p$ in the list.

For instance, in your second example $A = \{540, 648, 810, 648, 720\}$, the powers of $3$ are $\{3,4,4,4,2\}$. The second-lowest number in this multi-set $3$, so the power of $3$ in the result is $3$. (Here it is important that we consider a multiset, because if the lowest number occurs twice, we want it to count as the second-lowest.)

So you just have to maintain a list of the lowest two powers so far found, for each prime, and factorise each element of $A$, updating the list as you go.